# Get value of key with dynamic where clause in Appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings

I want to get the value of key with dynamic where clause in `appSettings` portion in `web.config` project (ASP.NET and C#) like this:

```
key="test" value="Select * from table where id=Textbox1.Text"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// Get sql query and add where clause to it.
string sqlString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"] + " where id=@id";


// Execute sqlString 
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value = Textbox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

**Edit**

C# for prevent [SQL injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx), stop executing commands that do this. You should use `SqlParameter`.

Comment: This is dodgy and open SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am using the below code, but it is not showing anything:            
var sql1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"] + "where id= " + TextBox1.Text; 
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               
But without TextBox1.Text, it is showing data. is it correct ?

Comment: @helal Please `upvote` and `accept` this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes I know this may be dangerous, but he may have to do it in this way.

Comment: No he doesn't. Use parameterized queries if not Stored Procedures, don't give shit advice on here.

Comment: If I use with this query ” where id=TextBox1.Text”  in code, how group by/order by will be used in Appsettings. Suppose, “select  position, count(position) from table where id=TextBox1.Text group by position order by “…
Please assist..

Comment: @helal you can add group by or order by in end of `sqlString` like `...  where id= " + Textbox1.Text + " order by id "`.

Comment: This is so bad, even if the TextBox contains a quote the whole thing will fail. Please amend your answer.

Comment: Actually..i would like to do it in appsettings. Is it possible ?

Comment: @helal Yes. It is possible but As Jeremy **Thompson said**, **SQL injection attack** might happen.

Comment: Yes..Jeremy Thompson is right. But it has been required for one query. can u please describes how it will be in appsetings?

Comment: @ Ali Soltani..Thanks for updating. Actually all portions of  query will be in Appsettings. Can please assist me to do it in appsettings...please help

Comment: @helal What do you mean by all portions of query will be in `Appsettings`?

Comment: @helal Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.